# How to upload image for a product using API in and set Product properties in Spree in iOS application

Tags: ios, spree

In my iOS app, i m creating product using spree API. Product is created successfully now i want to upload image for that product. But i not able to pass image to spree server. I  use url "http://serverAddress:3000/api/images.json?token=" but dont fine how and what are the parameters to be pass. Pls help.Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with API:

1. You must resize your image to usual spree sizes: large, mini, original, product, small.
2. You can make a POST request for your variant and get info about all images in response. The main info - `<id>` of new image. Note, that your server must take a big string  from your client.
3. You must upload this images to folder `../public/spree/products/<id>`

Comment: The simplest way is using a cloud storage and third party application which will work with uploaded images. But if your way to upload images directly from java app - you must write the post request to upload image and post request for inform spree about new image. Also, you need to write controller action for it inside your Spree app.